# Delete button in Django

Tags: jquery, django

I am using Django , i have written my views and model for delete button. but when i use the delete button , it deletes the data but it's showable untill i don't reload the page. here is my jquery . please help.

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
         appname = $('.delete').data('appname');
         modelname = $('.delete').data('modelname');
         pk = $('.delete').data('pk');
         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "/delete_button/" + appname + "/" + modelname + "/" + pk + "/"

         });
```

Comment: you're not doing anything to remove it from the page there. and using GET for deletes is generally considered a bad idea.

Comment: What do you need to cancel ?

Comment: Use $(this) instead of repeating $(.delete), to ensure the correct element is used

Comment: so what to do for remove the things with ajax call , actually i m new in jquery so don't have much idea. please help

Comment: You should use POST or DELETE for delete requests

Comment: i need to do in such a way : once i clicked the button , data should be deleted (which is done with ajax call) and should be removed , which is not done. so what should i do in my jquery??

Comment: can you please tell me with the code hint. i m new in jquery. please. it would  be great help

Comment: To delete the data from the page with jquery, you could use $(element).remove() (element obviously the element you want to remove)

Answer (score 0):

Use another http type `type: 'DELETE'`

After you deleted the resource on server you has to handle the deletion in the frontend as well. 
Maybe you can delete the frontend element which holds your element.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/delete_button/" + appname + "/" + modelname + "/" + pk + "/",
    type: "DELETE",
    success: function() {
        // Remove the HTML Element which represents you data
        $('.listelement').remove( "#" + pk )
    }
});
```